# What exactly does a .Net Matrix3D Transform() do / why am I getting "- infinity"?

Tags: c#, wpf, matrix, 3d

I'm trying to do a perspective transform on some 3D points.  (if it helps, I'm trying to apply the algorithm described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows.ui.xaml.media.media3d.matrix3d.aspx)).  But basically, I have a Matrix3D with the following values:

```
 HasInverse = true
 IsAffine = false   
 IsIdentity = false     
 M11 = 1.000000000000000    
 M12 = 0.0  
 M13 = 0.0  
 M14 = 0.0  
 M21 = 0.0  
 M22 = 1.000000000000000    
 M23 = 0.0  
 M24 = 0.0  
 M31 = 0.0  
 M32 = 0.0  
 M33 = -1.0101010101010102  
 M34 = 0.0  
 M44 = 0.0  
 OffsetX = 100  
 OffsetY = -1.0101010101010102
 OffsetZ = 0.0
```

When I apply a Transform using this matrix to a point of 310,120,0 . . .

```
  Point3D p = new Point3D(310, 120, 0);
  Point3D pointResult = new Point3D();
  pointResult = (Point3D)TheMatrix.Transform(p);
```

... I get (Infinity, Infinity, -Infinity) in the result.    What **exactly** does the *transform()* method do and why do I get that result?   The MSDN just says that method . . .

> Transforms the specified Point3D by the Matrix3D and returns the
>   result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Point3D` is first converted to a vector in homogeneous coordinates by appending a 1:

```
p_h = (310, 120, 0, 1)
```

Then, the transformation is applied as a multiplication:

```
p_h* = p_h * M
     = (410, 119, 0, 0)
```

Then, a w-clip is performed (which is necessary for perspective transforms). The w-clip divides the vector by its w-component (the last dimension). Since this is zero, you get an infinite result.

The problem is the matrix' `M44`. Set this to 1 and you should be fine. At least, the last column of the matrix should contain some values. If they are all zero, you will always get an infinite result.

Answer (score 1):

Traversing the source code is slightly painful, but here's what I can glean... `Transform` internally calls a method called `MultiplyPoint` (both source methods shown below), which generates a variable `w`, the sum of the products of x, y, z and corresponding values, _m11, _m21, _m31.  These variables result from being multiplied by the reciprocal and transpose in a method called `NormalizedAffineInvert`. I won't post all the source code, but [here's the link](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/WIN_WINDOWS/lh_tools_devdiv_wpf/Windows/wcp/Core/System/Windows/Media3D/Matrix3D@cs/1/Matrix3D@cs).

All I can imagine is happening is that `w` ends up equalling 0 somehow.  Since you say `IsAffine = false`, you enter the division logic and dividing by zero thus causes `Infinity`. Note that calling the public method `Invert()` will interally call `NormalizedAffineInvert`. Are you ever calling this method?

```
    #region Transformation Services

    /// <summary>
    ///  Transforms the given Point3D by this matrix, projecting the 
    ///  result back into the W=1 plane. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="point">Point to transform. 
    /// <returns>Transformed point.</returns>
    public Point3D Transform(Point3D point)
    {
        MultiplyPoint(ref point); 
        return point;
    }
```

MultiplyPoint:

```
    internal void MultiplyPoint(ref Point3D point)
    {
        if (IsDistinguishedIdentity) 
            return;

        double x = point.X; 
        double y = point.Y;
        double z = point.Z; 

        point.X = x*_m11 + y*_m21 + z*_m31 + _offsetX;
        point.Y = x*_m12 + y*_m22 + z*_m32 + _offsetY;
        point.Z = x*_m13 + y*_m23 + z*_m33 + _offsetZ; 

        if (!IsAffine) 
        { 
            double w = x*_m14 + y*_m24 + z*_m34 + _m44;

            point.X /= w;
            point.Y /= w;
            point.Z /= w;
        } 
    }
```